# Is there an app that lets me mark points of interest while I'm cycling?

Tags: commuter, gps

I have a phone with wifi only. Nevertheless, GPS tracking still works in apps like Wahoo Fitness so long as my location is turned on: as useful as it is creepy.

When I'm out cycling, I'll notice yard waste in the neighbourhood that I'd like to collect later for compost in the garden. It would be nice if I could quickly mark on a map a 'point of interest' that I can review later without having to come to a stop and write it down, or figure out an address.

Is there any app that can do this?

Comment: This is pretty tangential to cycling. However, smartphone cameras geotag the location of all photos, so taking a picture of the thing in question should work.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might be more suitable for this.

Comment: I agree it's worth trying softwarerecs.stackexchange.com but I would stress the importance of following their rules for asking good questions. Out of all the SE sites I use, it stands out as one where it seems the most worthwhile sticking to the rules. With your 6k+ rep across the network I'm sure you'll know what I mean.

Comment: Refrained from voting to close this, but answers have become a list of products, which is off topic. .

Comment: @mattnz agreed, it's really borderline.  I gave an answer, but on reflection i have also voted to close

Answer (score 1):

[OsmAnd](https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd) can do this.  You can download a small number of maps in the free version and a number limited only by your storage in the paid version.  You do not need any data coverage to use OsmAnd.

As a bonus, you can also use it for offline bicycle navigation/routing, although you should always verify manually that its routing is reasonable, as I've ended up quite in the bush sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

[Locus Map](https://www.locusmap.app/) can do this, and can work offline if you download map & routing data before.

Answer (score 0):

Strava is able to make use of geotagged photos as long as they are added through the app.
https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216917387-Add-a-Photo-to-an-Activity